# onmousemove Event Not Firing

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I've searched through the answers provided in this blog and others without any resolution.  Help is greatly appreciated.

I have an onmousemove event that is executing the first item in the list of events to fire but won't execute the second.
            `document.getElementById("map_image_africa").onmousemove = maps.redraw; learnPanel.redraw;`

The issue doesn't appear to be browser-specific; it occurs in Chrome and Safari. Haven't tried firefox yet.

In Chrome, I can pull up the browser's console and execute `learnPanel.redraw();` and it works as expected.
Also, if I put an alert statement between the maps.redraw and learnPanel.redraw statements in the onmouseover event, the alert will execute as expected.

the learnPanel object is created with the code below

```
        LearnPanel.prototype = new Panel();
        LearnPanel.prototype.constructor = LearnPanel;
        function LearnPanel() {
        }
        LearnPanel.prototype.draw = function() {

            var br_element = document.createElement("br");


            /* country name */
            if(this.isCountryNamesSelected === "yes") {
                var temp_label;
                temp_label = document.createElement("label");
                temp_label.classList.add('quiz_question_heading_label');
                temp_label.innerHTML = "Country: ";

                this.flagColumnTab.appendChild(temp_label);

                this.labelCountryName = document.createElement("label");
                this.labelCountryName.id = "country_name";
                this.labelCountryName.classList.add('quiz_question_label');

                this.flagColumnTab.appendChild(this.labelCountryName);
                this.flagColumnTab.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

            }
            /* capital */
            if(this.isCapitalNamesSelected === "yes") {
                var temp_label;
                temp_label = document.createElement("label");
                temp_label.classList.add('quiz_question_heading_label');
                temp_label.innerHTML = "Capital: ";

                this.flagColumnTab.appendChild(temp_label);

                this.labelCapitalName = document.createElement("label");
                this.labelCapitalName.id = "capital";
                this.labelCapitalName.classList.add('quiz_question_label');

                this.flagColumnTab.appendChild(this.labelCapitalName);
                this.flagColumnTab.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

            }
            /* flag */
            if(this.isCountryFlagsSelected === "yes") {

                this.flagImage = document.createElement("img");
                this.flagImage.id = "flag_image";
                this.flagImage.src = "/images/flags/_flag.jpeg";
                this.flagImage.alt = "flag logo";

                this.flagColumnTab.appendChild(this.flagImage);

                this.flagColumnTab.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                this.flagColumnTab.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

            }


        }
        LearnPanel.prototype.redraw = function() {


            alert('redrawing learnPanel');
            /* country name */
            if(learnPanel.isCountryNamesSelected === "yes") {
                learnPanel.labelCountryName.innerHTML = maps.getCurrentDisplayCountryDown();
            }
            /* capital */
            if(learnPanel.isCapitalNamesSelected === "yes") {
                learnPanel.labelCapitalName.innerHTML = maps.getCurrentCountryCapitalDown();
            }
            /* flag */
            if(learnPanel.isCountryFlagsSelected === "yes") {
                learnPanel.flagImage.src = "/images/flags/" + maps.getCurrentFlagDown() + "_flag.jpeg";
                learnPanel.flagImage.alt = "flag of " + maps.getCurrentFlagDown();
            }
            /* head of state */
            /* famous landmark */

        }


        learnPanel = new LearnPanel();
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

What you need here is an **anonymous function**. When you are assigning functions for the `mousemove` property on `#map_large_africa`, you want to have two distinct functions occur. Unfortunately, because of the way you have written the following statement:

```
`document.getElementById("map_image_africa").onmousemove = maps.redraw; learnPanel.redraw;`
```

It is actually parsed thusly:

```
document.getElementById("map_image_africa").onmousemove = maps.redraw;

learnPanel.redraw;
```

Do you see the problem? The semi-colon acts as the end of a command. The map is redrawn on mousemove, but `learnPanel.redraw` not part of the `onmousemove` assignment, and that line is executed only once, right after the `onmousemove` property is assigned to `#map_image_africa`. By wrapping it in an [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Functions_as_event_handlers), you can execute more than one line of javascript at a time.

Try the following:

```
document.getElementById("map_image_africa").onmousemove = function() {
    maps.redraw();    // note that these lines have () after the method name.
    learnPanel.redraw();
}
```

---

While I have you, please note that directly modifying properties like `onmousemove` and `onclick` are discouraged, and **[Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event)** are the preferred way to interact with DOM elements, as it separates javascript from the HTML.

The above `onmousemove` assignment can (and should) be rewritten as such:

```
document.getElementById("map_image_africa").addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    maps.redraw();
    learnPanel.redraw();
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer - it resolved the issue.  I also took your advice on the eventListeners.  Thanks!